# Using English models with Spanish database in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've just linked my Rails app to a mysql database which has the table names and columns in Spanish. Now I solved the Spanish table names problem by setting `self.table_name = "table_name"` inside the `model.rb`. Now the next problem occurs when I want to call a data through joining tables. In this case I'm trying to call all the `ads` that belong the first `category`. When I try this as you see in the screenshot below, I get this error. It sees the `ad` table now `anuncio` which is the Spanish name. I'm a bit confused, because I thought that by doing `self.table_name = "table_name"` in every model Rails knows which table I mean. Does someone know what's going on here and how to solve it? See below all my code regarding the models and tables.

[image: Error Rails App]

Ad model:

```
class Ad < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "anuncios"
  has_many :ad_copies
  has_many :ad_addresses
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :magazines
  has_many :categories, through: :relationships
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Relationship model:

```
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "rel_anuncio"
  self.primary_key = "id_anuncio"
  belongs_to :ad, class_name: "anuncio", foreign_key: "id_anuncio", optional: true
  belongs_to :category, class_name: "categoria", foreign_key: "id_categoria", optional: true
  belongs_to :subcategory, class_name: "subcategoria", foreign_key: "id_subcategoria", optional: true
end
```

Category model:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "categorias"
  has_many :subcategories
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :ads, through: :relationships
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Subcategory model:

```
class Subcategory < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "subcategorias"
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :ads, through: :relationships
  belongs_to :category
end
```

You can see in the models above that I've been trying to get the relationship model to connect to the ad model with respectively the category and subcategory model, because these models have n:n relationship with each other. Before, when I was using an English database as practice, the `@categories.first.ads.count` worked, but changing to a Spanish database it suddenly stopped working. In the relationship table I'm also explicitly setting the foreign-key for each of the models.

Ads table (anuncios) schema:

```
create_table "anuncios", id: :integer, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "empresa", null: false
    t.string "tel", null: false
    t.string "fax_principal", null: false
    t.string "movil_principal", null: false
    t.string "email_principal", null: false
    t.string "web", null: false
    t.string "facebook", null: false
    t.string "horario_v_principal", null: false
    t.string "horario_i_principal", null: false
    t.string "direccion_principal", null: false
    t.string "poblacion_principal", null: false
    t.string "activo", limit: 2, null: false
    t.string "tam_anuncio", null: false
    t.string "twitter", null: false
    t.string "link", limit: 2, null: false
    t.string "general", limit: 2, null: false
    t.string "isla", limit: 10, null: false
    t.string "subtitulo", null: false
    t.string "comentario", null: false
    t.datetime "modificacion", null: false
    t.integer "promo1", default: 0, null: false
    t.integer "promo2", default: 0, null: false
    t.string "instagram", null: false
    t.string "tel2", null: false
    t.string "tel3", null: false
    t.string "tel4", null: false
    t.string "movil2", null: false
    t.string "movil3", null: false
    t.string "movil4", null: false
  end
```

Relationship table (rel_anuncios) schema:

```
create_table "rel_anuncio", primary_key: ["id_anuncio", "id_categoria", "id_subcategoria"], force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer "id_anuncio", null: false
    t.integer "id_categoria", null: false
    t.integer "id_subcategoria", null: false
    t.integer "orden", null: false
  end
```

Categories table (categorias) schema:

```
create_table "categorias", id: :integer, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.string "nombre", null: false
    t.string "color", null: false
    t.string "activo", limit: 2, null: false
    t.string "bdd", limit: 7, null: false
    t.integer "orden", null: false
    t.integer "promoI", limit: 1, default: 0, null: false
    t.integer "promoF", limit: 1, default: 0, null: false
    t.integer "islas", limit: 1, default: 3, null: false
  end
```

Subcategories table (subcategorias) schema:

```
create_table "subcategorias", id: :integer, force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer "id_categoria", null: false
    t.string "nombre", null: false
    t.string "color", null: false
    t.string "activo", limit: 2, default: "si", null: false
    t.integer "orden", null: false
    t.integer "promoI", limit: 1, default: 0, null: false
    t.integer "promoF", limit: 1, default: 0, null: false
    t.integer "islas", limit: 1, default: 3, null: false
  end
```

**UPDATE:**

In response to @Jagdeep Singh comment I've changed my `relationship.rb` to look like this:

```
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "rel_anuncio"
  self.primary_key = "id_anuncio"
  belongs_to :ad, foreign_key: "id_anuncio", optional: true
  belongs_to :category, foreign_key: "id_categoria", optional: true
  belongs_to :subcategory, foreign_key: "id_subcategoria", optional: true
end
```

*I've taken away the class names.

After this change I get the following error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'rel_anuncio.category_id' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `anuncios` INNER JOIN `rel_anuncio` ON `anuncios`.`id` = `rel_anuncio`.`id_anuncio` WHERE `rel_anuncio`.`category_id` = 1
```

Here I can see that ActiveRecord is using in its sql statement `category_id` which should be `id_categoria` (see schema relationship table above). I have no idea how to make ActiveRecord use the right name for the foreign_key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You class names should be the actual **model names** (and not their table names) when defining associations. And as your association names follow the rails [conventions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-class-name) e.g. model for `belongs_to :ad` is `Ad`, and so on, you can omit specifying `class_name`:

```
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :ad, foreign_key: "id_anuncio", optional: true
  belongs_to :category, foreign_key: "id_categoria", optional: true
  belongs_to :subcategory, foreign_key: "id_subcategoria", optional: true
end
```

**Update**

More changes in association definitions after the recent error posted in comments:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subcategories, foreign_key: 'id_categoria'
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: 'id_categoria'
  has_many :ads, through: :relationships
  belongs_to :user
end

class Subcategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :relationships, foreign_key: 'id_subcategoria'
  has_many :ads, through: :relationships
  belongs_to :category, foreign_key: 'id_categoria'
end
```

Comment: Ok thanks @Jagdeep Singh. I've removed the class names. Now I get the following error on the page:

```Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'rel_anuncio.category_id' in 'where clause': SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `anuncios` INNER JOIN `rel_anuncio` ON `anuncios`.`id` = `rel_anuncio`.`id_anuncio` WHERE `rel_anuncio`.`category_id` = 1```

Comment: Thank you Jagdeep it worked. You've solved the riddle.